# Is it possible to skip an Automator action conditionally?

Tags: applescript, automator

I have an automator application/workflow that takes a bunch of input from the user and spits out an application that performs some specific functions when run, based on that input.  Basically I've made an application that creates applications.

Within the application, I would like to allow the user enter "N/A" (which is the default text already) for anything they want to skip, and have the workflow jump past a later action that asks for related input based on the first input that they chose to skip.

Is there any way to check a variable and depending on its content, skip past certain actions?

Comment: I don't see what else needs to be said to answer this question.  Either it's possible to conditionally skip an action in Automator, or it isn't.  I do have scripts at various points in the workflow yes, but that has nothing to do with needing to skip past standard actions based on the value of a variable.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear, I wanted to know if I can skip an action (such as for instance a Ask For Text block) based on the value of another variable.  Sounds like the answer is simply no, which is what I had concluded but thought I would try to confirm.

Comment: Since Automator is scriptable, you can use a script (`Run AppleScript` or whatever) to access the actions in a _workflow_ and set their `enabled` property as desired, but it would be helpful to see a minimal example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Aha very interesting.  OK I will see about making a cut-down simple version to illustrate.

Comment: @red_menace, I know one can use _code_ in a **Run AppleScript** _action_ to _disable/enable_ a subsequent _action_ in a _workflow_, but the OP is running his _workflow_ as an _application_... so that wouldn't be applicable unless it's opened in **Automator** and run as a _workflow_ not an _application_. Or is there also a way to do it when run as a standalone _application_?

Comment: JVC, Another thing to consider is, if you are just asking a series of questions and then using _scripting_ to create the _user application_ based on the responses, maybe the whole thing can be done in **AppleScript** in **Script Editor** and then saved as an _application_.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes I'm certain the whole thing could be done in AppleScript, and in fact that was another way I was considering going.  I'm just not much of an applescripter so automator is easier for me to work with, until I start wanting to get more complex like this.  I'll think about it.

Comment: It is disgusting the fact that Automator (and pretty much every macro recorder out there) doesn't have a simple "IF/ELSE" action. The few software that does have will throw a whole language learning in your face.